# How to set icon in main.xml by java code?

Tags: android

I want to change menu item icon when I touch menu item.
this is my code.but not working

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   switch (item.getItemId()) {

   case R.id.bq:
      MenuItem a = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.bq);
      int m = R.drawable.ic_action_star_d;
      a.setIcon(m);

        }

return false;

}
```

and this is act.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/bq"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Rate!"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_star"
            android:actionProviderClass=
                "android.intent.action.Search" />
</menu>
```

Comment: `but not working` - what does this mean?  It tells us nothing, er, except it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(final int featureId, final android.view.MenuItem item)
{
    item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    return true;
};
```